# Does PHP Include make your code faster?

Tags: php, performance, include

I have an ad network script like the following

```
http://cdn.domain.com/ad.php?variables=etc
```

We have about 10,000 hits a second and we are looking at some improvements for our Pseudo code - this is what I have in mind - my question is - would PHP includes slow down my script like the if else codes and would it be worth minifying the PHP on this page:

```
<?php
// mysql connect
// get variables from publisher
// if publisher has no ads show advertise here banner 
// if resolution from variables is 125x125 show that banner or whatever resolution from the vars
// example www.noadhere.com/image/advertishere_{var}125px.jpg
// if publisher has no ads show advertise here banner and also updated mysql with page views for this publisher

// if publisher has a banner then show it and update mysql with page views
// show also the click code that redirects and updates the record with a hit click
?>
```

I have updated the code. This is the Phase 1 draft for those who are interested. I think it is so much simpler and I am going to minify this - even though there may not be need - we had 4 mysql actions happening. And now there are 3 - I just made the update views a one liner.

```
# mysql
$c=mysql_connect("sqlmaster.adserver.com","user","************");
mysql_select_db("adserver", $c);

# vars
$a=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["z"]);//id
$z=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["z"]);//zone
$h=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["h"]);//height
$w=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["w"]);//width
$d=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");//date
$u=mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);//url

# constructor

    # do we have ads?
    $r1=mysql_query("");
    if(mysql_affected_rows()==0){

        # empty ad code unit
        echo 'Blog Empty';

    } else {

        # we have ads - so show random click code
        echo 'Click here .php ? and redirect';

    }

    # update mysql view table for this ad unit - empty or filled
    $r2=mysql_query("");

# end constructor
mysql_close($c);
```

Any suggestions on improving this would be welcomed. I think the mysql_real_escape is slow.

Comment: Minify PHP? As in "strip comments and white space so the PHP engine needs to parse less bytes"?

Comment: Benchmark and profile, wash rinse repeat. Those are your only realistic options.

Comment: If you really concern about the performance..you have to think big & have to work on logic of memcache , apc , query optimization etc..

Comment: Yes - complete minify of PHP code onto a few lines. @RikeshShah - the logic I have in the Pseudo code was just the top of my head. We already have three MySQL cloud servers on loadbalance and also run memcache, APC and also run PHP on a highly optimized Nginx server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using include only slows down your script by the amount of time it takes your server to open the file, which is usually just a fraction of a second. So it wouldn't drastically slow down your script execution.

Comment: "just a fraction of a second" is not very specific. With 10,000 hits **per second**, every fraction of a second counts! Do you have any actual numbers or are you only guessing?

Comment: Use APC, and you don't have to worry about the miniscule costs of file opening for include files

Comment: We have APC, memcache, Nginx and are on a Rackspace Cloud server which is highly optimized. I am just thinking of spinning a separate server just to handle the Ad display queries and the Ad click queries. We actually get around 5000 to 9000 on an average day and it can spike depending on the sites. But we are about to grow rapidly so that is why the Cloud scaling option + this code solution must be robust.

Comment: I think the best approach is using comments here - keep a .src file with comments and indentation and then keep a live .php file with complete minification including variable names $a was $apple and .src file will have notes on this. MySQL performance so far is OK - we have 1 master and 2 slaves and running load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

When using a PHP cache, includes really don't matter that much. However, there definitely is a very minor difference.

My own build scripts automatically replace includes with "normal" code, using a self-made syntax that's backwards compatible with PHP:

```
/*safeinclude*/ include 'file.php';
```

My parser then reads the PHP file and notices this include. It grabs the contents of the `file.php` file and replaces the include with this code (after some cleanup, such as removing the leading `<?php` tag). It then gets saved to the `bin` directory, which is where the live files are.

This approach works very well, but you must always check for the `<?php` and `?>` tags. Also, you'd have to split `src` and `bin` directories, because you can't change anything that's already live anymore.

Your primary focus area for optimizations should probably be the database though, and other CPU-intensive operations such as loops.

Comment: Appreciated this comment. I am using IF ELSE rather than loops for this reason. I have found in the past and even know - I noticed Loops performance impact myself without any tools

Comment: I still think this is a poor way of doing things. Just have a .src.private or something and have a .php file - or use WordCompress API so you can have clean indented commented code your end and public live files are all compressed and minified. This approach will get messy as I have seen lazy developers not updating src code etc...

Comment: In my case there's a daily build cycle which simply overwrites all files in `bin`. Developers that don't update their code properly will notice that it's gone at 12 AM.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of making code run faster. Usually splitting code into separate files will not improve performance (selectively including just the code you need instead of a huge library will probably help).

You may have noticed that there aren't a lot of off-the shelf solutions for minifying PHP code - there's a good reason for that. It won't make a lot of difference to the execution time (it does for javascript mainly due to the reduction in network transfer time - not in the reduction in parsing time). PHP code doesn't go across the network. And if you want to reduce parsing time, then using an opcode cache is a much effective solution.

Since this is presumably a significant revenue stream, then you should have the skills to know this already. However a lot of performance improvements come about by trial and error (and careful experiment design and measurement) - you might want to invest some time in developing these facilities.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about running if and else's is that only the code that is needed to be ran will run. Included pages are loaded in a split of a second and do not really make any difference on the speed. Most big websites have long trails of included files and you don't really notice it.